# Custom user registration email - Drupal 6

Tags: media, users, navigation, emails

I want to add image icons for Facebook, Twitter etc with associated links and Join Us hyperlink like Join Us to the user registration email.

Can anyone give me idea?

Answer (score 1):

you can create and send system html emails using mimemail module and a wysiwyg editor http://drupal.org/project/mimemail (or even http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail )

Answer (score 1):

You can control the content of registration emails through the Drupal admin interface...
D6: http://example.dev/admin/user/settings
D7: http://example.dev/admin/config/people/accounts

There are a number of different templates for various emails sent out to users. By default, these emails are in plain text. You'll need a module (like [HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail)) to enable sending HTML emails. Then, you should be able to edit any of the built-in user email templates to include images and links.